# Palantir-Foundry : OOM when running inference with a pretrained NLP model from Hugging Face

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark, huggingface-transformers, palantir-foundry

I am new to foundry and I have been trying to run a pre-trained sentence embedding model from hugging face. I followed this documentation https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/integrate-models/language-models-add-new/

I successfully imported the model I chose, but when running inference on a dataset (using python transform) I get an OOM error ("Connection to driver lost") unless I limit the number of rows in the dataframe.

The dataset is a pyspark dataframe, but to run inference on it I need to change it to a pandas dataframe ( hence the OOM I assume), from what I understand it's because the model adapter (huggingface_adapters.EmbeddingAdapter) requires a pandas dataframe  as input.

Is it possible to change the input from pandas df to a pyspark df ? If it is , how ?
If not ,what kind of workaround can I do to run the model on all the data ?

Here is what my code for inference looks like ( can't share the real code)

````
from transforms.api import transform, Input, Output
from palantir_models.transforms import ModelInput

@transform(
    inference_output=Output("/path/to/inference_output"),
    dataset=Input("/path/to/dataset"),
    model=ModelInput("/path/to/model"),
)
def compute(inference_output, dataset, model):
    df=dataset.dataframe().select("text_to_embed").withColumnRenamed("text_to_embed","text").toPandas()       
    inference_results = model.transform(df)  
    inference = inference_results.output_data
    inference_output.write_pandas(inference)```
````